# Wrapping part of html

Tags: jquery, html

I have something like this :

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <a></a>
    <p></p>
    <div class="foot"></div>
</div>

<div id="bar">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="foot"></div>
</div>
```

And I would like something like this the simpliest way possible :

```
<div id="foo">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a></a>
        <p></p>
        <div class="foot"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bar">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="foot"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(I added two wrappers)

Is this possible using jquery? I wanted to do things like $('#foo .menu').after(''), but I can't add partial html code.

Answer (score 1):

Target all the children, but not the menu:

```
$('#foo >:not(.menu)').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qejx0mj4/

I left it as an exercise for the reader, but obvious you could either include both selectors, or use another class and wrap each result in an each:

e.g.

```
$('#foo >:not(.menu),#bar >:not(.menu)'').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">');
```

or add a common class

```
$('.pickme').each(function(){
   $(">:not(.menu)", this).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">')
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qejx0mj4/1/

The last one would be my preference.

Note: You do not need to close single level elements in jQuery

e.g. you can use `'<div class="wrapper">'` and not `'<div class="wrapper"></div>'`

Comment: this wont work as it will wrap all of them in one wrapper. https://jsfiddle.net/bgucvw2v/

Comment: ohh. so op has to write this twice for foo and bar divs

Comment: @Milind Anantwar: Covered all options I can think of... :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that everything is wrapped into the wrapper, it's not iterating... Do you know why?

Comment: @Eko: Are you using the last version shown? If not please show the exact code you are now trying in a JSFiddle etc.

Comment: Well the problem is that I want to do that in each div. There's a wrapper in #bar as well

Comment: Did you try the last example I keep referring to? It does them all separately as you wanted. It only requires the addition of a common selector (e.g.a class). If you still have a problem implementing this, please be specific :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.menu').each(function(){
  $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>')
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0L6jxsms/)**

Comment: that wasn't updated when i was commenting... :). though the question remains same. Do OP have to write it twice??

Answer (score 1):

use css selector in jquery like below

```
$("#foo>*:not(.menu)").wrapAll("<div 'wrapper'></div>");
```

and check the link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9dhevv5L/)

Comment: The `*` is not needed. Also the closing `</div>` is not needed with jQuery. Otherwise you have the exact same result I came up with :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, the other solutions proposed by now were not looping over each div :

```
$('div').each(function(index) {
        $('div:nth-child(' + index + ') > :not(.menu)').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">');
    });
```